# How can I call a function from a method of the same name?

Tags: dart

I want to have a `print` method in my class, also I want to be able to use `print` inside it

example:

```
class A {
  String val;
  void print() {
    print(val);
  }
}
```

using `print` will refer to the method of class `A`, how can I specify the full path of the method I want to call?

Comment: Where is the method you want to call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of different ways to resolve the name conflict:

- As [Christopher Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289547/) mentioned, you can explicitly import `dart:core` with [a prefix](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#specifying-a-library-prefix).  Note that if you don't want to prefix *everything* from `dart:core`, you could import it twice, once into the global namespace and again into the prefixed namespace:

  ```dart
  import 'dart:core';
  import 'dart:core' as core;
  ```

  Then you would be able to explicitly use `core.print` within your `print` method and use `print` normally everywhere else.

  Note that if you have a method trying to call a global function with the same name within the same Dart library, you could split your code into multiple files, or your library could import itself with a prefix:

  `foo.dart`:

  ```dart
  import 'foo.dart' as foo;

  class SomeClass {
     void f() => foo.f();
  }

  void f() {
     // Do stuff.
  }
  ```
- You alternatively could explicitly create another reference to the normal `print` function with a different name:

  ```dart
  final _print = print;

  class A {
    String val;
    void print() {
      _print(val);
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: I've used your solution on my last commit here https://github.com/ammaratef45/dart_stack/commit/c2ac64bb73413dab3c96d1bef4d677eeefd7ab84 so thanks again for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're trying to call the `print` function of `dart:core`.

You can explicitly import `dart:core` and specify a prefix for it with the `as` keyword:

```dart
import 'dart:core' as core;

class A {
  core.String val;
  void print() {
    core.print(val);
  }
}
```

Likely the biggest issue with this is now you have to have to prefix *everything* that's in `dart:core` like the `String` in your example.

Comment: You could import `dart:core` into the `core` namespace and again into the global namespace to avoid needing to prefix everything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
import "dart:core";
import "dart:core" as core show print;

class Class {
  static print(_string) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      core.print(_string);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the existing answers.

Comment: Yes it does: it sums the direct "core.print" call without that "final _print = print;" with the double import, the first normal one and the second one with the alias core and introducing the "show print" that permit to access the print method only to keep clean the logic of the double import.

Comment: Combining `show print` with an import prefix doesn't provide much additional benefit, but okay.   In the future, you should provide some explanation about what points you're trying to emphasize and should avoid code-only answers. (BTW, the `final _print = print` thing from my answer is a completely separate approach unrelated to the double `import`.)